# mongodb autoincreement in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using php and mongodb. I want to autoincreement the id. When i am using this code

```
db.online.insert({
field_id: "register_id",
nextId: 0
},
{
field_id: "user_id",
nextId: 0
});


function getNextIdOnline(field){
var ret = db.online.findAndModify({
    query: { field_id: field },
    update: { $inc: { nextId: 1 } },
    new: true
});    
return ret.nextId;
}

db.online.insert({
 _id: getNextIdOnline("register_id"),
 userid: "8223456",
 username:"Kumar"
});
```

It is working as fine in mongodb terminal. I want to call to function in php. when using this code

```
$mng1 = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/db");
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
    $proccode = 'getNextIdOnline("register_id")';
$bulk->update(['userid' => $userphone], ['_id' =>  new MongoCode($proccode),'userid' => $userphone, 'username' => $username, 'active_time' => $today], ['upsert' => 'true']);

$mng->executeBulkWrite("db.online", $bulk);
```

Then it shows the error is

> Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoCode' not found.

I got  the reference from 
http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2010/08/getting-started-with-stored-procedures-in-mongodb.html

How can auto increement the field using php? Please help me.

Is there any substitute for mongocode?

Comment: MongoCode is from legacy driver, use [MongoDB\BSON\Javascript](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-javascript.php) instead

Comment: How can i use in php

Comment: Sorry Fazil, my comment is a **comment** not the answer. I am just pointing that the article you are referring to is 7 years old, and `MongoCode` has been deprecated long time ago. The new Mongodb driver for php you are using in first lines of your snippet `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` has no `MongoCode` class, hence the error. I have provided a reference to alternative class in the new driver with sincere hope that with small effort you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: Thank u. but i didn't get any solution. Any substitute for mongocode?

Comment: hmmm, ok I can repeat it 3rd time, MongoDB\BSON\Javascript is a substitute for MongoCode. Hope it helps.